# How to send an image from HTTP client to http server listening on this URL(http://localhost:8000/test)

Tags: httpserver

I need to send an image to server and in serve process the image and need to store into temporary path. i just created a connection between client and server without using socket. but do not know how to send an image to server from http client. thanks help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using web container like apache/nginx or one you write it yourself?
If you are wondering how to decode the tcp packet in your own server, just upload a file to a server and grasp the http packet to see the detail of the protocol